# Unable to Cast Enum to Int

Tags: c#, reflection, enums

I have the following code. I need it to create a `List` of `KeyValuePair<string, string>` with the name and value of each enum value in the specified enum type.

```
public static List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> GetEnumList<TEnum>() where TEnum : struct
{
    if (!typeof(TEnum).IsEnum)
        throw new ArgumentException("Type must be an enumeration");
    List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
    foreach (TEnum e in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)))
        list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(e.ToString(), ((int)e).ToString()));
    return list;
}
```

However, the expression `((int)e).ToString()` generates the following error.

> Cannot convert type 'TEnum' to 'int'

I'm just trying to cast an enum instance to an integer. Can anyone tell me why this won't work?

**EDIT:**

I tried this version:

```
enum Fruit : short
{
    Apple,
    Banana,
    Orange,
    Pear,
    Plum,
}

void Main()
{
    foreach (var x in EnumHelper.GetEnumList<Fruit>())
        Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", x.Value, x.Key);
}

public static List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> GetEnumList<TEnum>() where TEnum : struct
{
    if (!typeof(TEnum).IsEnum)
        throw new ArgumentException("Type must be an enumeration");
    List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
    foreach (TEnum e in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)))
    {
        list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(e.ToString(), ((int)(dynamic)e).ToString()));
    }
    return list;
}
```

But this gives me the error:

> Cannot convert type 'System.Enum' to 'int'

Comment: your `TEnum` will never be an `int` because `where TEnum : struct` so it will always be an structure

Comment: @WiiMaxx: `struct` just means it's a value type, which `int` is.

Comment: but how do you get an `int` from [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ah19swz4(v=vs.80).aspx) because i understood an struct as an simple container for values

Comment: You are thinking of a structure declaration. `struct` has a different meaning when used after the `where` clause like this.

Comment: ah ok that's new to me i will google it :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`TEnum` is - per constraint - a struct. It isn't guaranteed to be an enum.

However, because you are enforcing that constraint at runtime, you can utilize the fact the each enum implements `IConvertible`:

```
foreach (IConvertible e in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)))
{
    list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(
        e.ToString(),
        e.ToType(
            Enum.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(TEnum)),
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).ToString()));
}
```

Other approaches which all have downsides are:

You can first cast to `object` and then to `int`.

Please note that this will fail at runtime if the underlying type of the enum is anything other than `int`.

This can be overcome by casting to `dynamic` before casting to `int`:

```
((int)(dynamic)e).ToString()
```

However, this again has some problems:

If the enum is of type `long`, `ulong` or `uint` it will return incorrect values. You can reduce the problem by casting to `ulong` instead of `int` but that will still return invalid values for negative enum values.

Comment: Worth noting that the cast to `object`/`Enum` and to `int` is still a box+unbox, though. Of course, that may not be significant if they are going to `ToString()` it anyway ;p

Comment: @MarcGravell: That's correct. BTW: The cast has to be to `object` instead of `Enum` - corrected the answer.

Comment: @Danial: `((int)(dynamic)e).ToString()` gives me the error `Cannot convert type 'System.Enum' to 'int'`.

Comment: @JonathanWood: That sounds very strange. Please update your question with the exact code you are using now. BTW: I tested that code. It works. It has to be something else you changed or something...

Comment: @JonathanWood: How are you calling that method? What .NET framework are you using?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: I added the call. I'm actually running in LinqPAD. Does this run okay for you?

Comment: @JonathanWood: Yeah, I too tested it in LINQPad. However, your code isn't runing, because you are using `EnumHelper.GetEnumList`. Try to fix it to use just `GetEnumList`.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: Very strange. My `EnumHelper` class contains extension method and so was declared as `static`. Removing `static` causes it to work fine; otherwise, I get the error previously described. I don't understand that at all.

Comment: @JonathanWood: I can't reproduce that. Care to upload a test project?

Comment: @JonathanWood: I added another alternative which doesn't require the use of `dynamic` and will always return the correct value.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: Thanks for all your help, but do you have any idea why I get the error `'TEnum' does not contain a definition for 'ToType' and no extension method 'ToType' accepting a first argument of type 'TEnum' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`? I get this error both in LinqPad and Visual Studio.

Comment: @JonathanWood: Have a close look at the code I posted. The variable type of the foreach loop variable is no longer `TEnum`. It is now `IConvertible`. An alternative approach would be to change the constraint to include `IConvertible` as Martin showed in his answer.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: Right you are. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

The only safe way to do this, without nowing the base type, is to use the methods created for it! The methods inside the Enum-class. Even you could try to make use of the `IConvertable` interface.

```
// Get underlying type, like int, ulong, etc.
Type underlyingType = Enum.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T); 
// Convert the enum to that type.
object underlyingValue = e.ToType(underlyingType, null);
// Convert that value to string. 
string s = underlyingValue.ToString();
```

Or in short:

```
string s = e.ToType(Enum.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T)), null).ToString();
```

You can implement it in your code like this:

```
public static List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> GetEnumList<TEnum>() 
          where TEnum : struct, IConvertible
{
    if (!typeof(TEnum).IsEnum)
        throw new ArgumentException("Type must be an enumeration");
    List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
    foreach (TEnum e in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)))
    {
        list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>
        (
            e.ToString(), 
            e.ToType(Enum.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(TEnum)), null).ToString()
        ));
    }
    return list;
}
```

If you do not want to use `IConvertable`, try to use the `Convert` class:

```
string s = Convert.ChangeType(e, Enum.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(TEnum))).ToString();
```

Comment: `Enum.ToObject` is the other way around. It converts a numeric value to an enum member. Executing your code - after fixing the compiler error - yields an `ArgumentException`: *Type provided must be an Enum.Parameter name: enumType*.

Comment: None of this compiles for me.

Comment: @MartinMulder: Yes, that is the best approach. My answer also shows this since a few minutes :)

Comment: @MartinMulder: I didn't. Have a look at the edit histories. My answer contained that code before you corrected your answer.

Comment: @Perhapse: But my mistake was not in the that put you on the right track to `GetUnderlyingType`. But leave it at this. Lets call it a tie.